# Filter out rows by hardcoded list in MySQL performance

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I have a hardcoded list of values like: 1,5,7,8 and so on.

And I must filter out rows from table that have ID in list above, so I do something like this:

```
Select
* 
from myTable m
   left join othertable t
   on t.REF_ID = m.ID
where m.ID not in (1,5,7,8...)
```

But when I have more values (like 1000) and more rows (100) in othertable and myTable this query starts to be slow. I have an index on REF_ID and ID. It seems that the part "where m.ID in (1,5,7,8) is the problem.

Is there faster way to filter out rows by hardcoded list of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your list in a temporary table as `temptable.ID` and doing

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable m
LEFT JOIN othertable t ON t.REF_ID = m.ID
LEFT JOIN temptable ON m.ID = temptable.ID
WHERE temptable.ID IS NULL
```